# invalid validators in Symfony - sfForkedApplyPlugin

Tags: php, symfony1

> ```
>     public function configure()
>         {
>             parent::configure();
>
>             $email = $this->getWidget('email');
>             $class = get_class($email);
>             $this->setWidget('email2', 
>                     new $class( array(), array('maxlength' =>
> ```
>
> $email->getAttribute('maxlength') )
>                   ) );
>                   $this->widgetSchema->moveField( 'email2',
>   sfWidgetFormSchema::AFTER, 'email' );
>
> $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('sfApplyApply[%s]');
>                   $this->widgetSchema->setFormFormatterName('list');
>
> ```
>             $this->setValidator('email', new sfValidatorAnd(
> ```
>
> array(
>                       new sfValidatorEmail( array('required' => true,
>   'trim' => true) ),
>                       new sfValidatorString( array('required' => true,
>   'max_length' => 80) ),
>                       new sfValidatorDoctrineUnique(
>                               array( 'model' => 'sfGuardUserProfile',
>   'column' => 'email'),
>                               array('invalid' => 'An account with that
>   email address already exists. If you have forgotten your password,
>   click "cancel", then "Reset My Password."') )
>                   )));
>
> ```
>             $this->setValidator('email2', new sfValidatorEmail( 
>                     array( 'required' => true, 'trim' => true )));
>
>             $schema = $this->validatorSchema;
>
>             // Hey Fabien, adding more postvalidators is kinda
> ```
>
> verbose!
>                   $postValidator = $schema->getPostValidator();
>
> ```
>             $postValidators = array( 
>                 new sfValidatorSchemaCompare( 'password',
> ```
>
> sfValidatorSchemaCompare::EQUAL,
>                               'password2', array(), array('invalid' =>
>   'The passwords did not match.') ),
>                       new sfValidatorSchemaCompare( 'email',
>   sfValidatorSchemaCompare::EQUAL,
>                               'email2', array(), array('invalid' => 'The
>   email addresses did not match.') ) );
>
> ```
>             if( $postValidator )
>             {
>                 $postValidators[] = $postValidator;
>             }
>
>             $this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator( new
> ```
>
> sfValidatorAnd($postValidators) );
>               }
>       }

why if is in database another user with same email then i have two error - first with this information, and second - The emails did not match.

how can i fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to dump the values contained in email and email2 ?